# Mule - SFTP remote archiving

Tags: mule

I am processing a large csv file in Mule from an SFTP server.

I need to read it in from an input directory, move it to a tmp directory and when finished move it to an archive directory.

The first two i can accomplish easily. But what is the best way to move it to the archive folder when finished?

The archiveDir option on the sftp transport only archives a copy on the local server where mule is running but not on the remote sftp server.

Comment: Looking for the same functionality. Best candidate at the moment is to perform an SFTP copy on Flow completion.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in the mule flow while connecting to sftp server.

```
<flow name="receive_files">
....// sftp connection configuration
....
    <wire-tap>
                    <file:outbound-endpoint path="${global.workdir}/dir1/dir2/archive/inbound/#[function:datestamp-yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss.SSS]" />
                </wire-tap>
...
..
</flow>
```

Check out: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/sftp/sftp-copy-move

Comment: Can you show the complete working code or documentation related to it. That's how this answer would be useful.

Comment: Check out documentation, If there is something provided in question I would be able to suggest something.

Comment: Accepted, but the question is looking for mule of earlier version and so am I.